# Change FontAwesome text and fontfamily with c# - xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added the FontAwesome fonts in my solutions (android and ios) and i can use it from xaml without any problem.

My xaml code

```
   <Label x:Name="Star1" Text="&#xf005;" FontSize="22" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}"/>
```

App.xaml

```
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                    x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid"> 
          <On Platform="Android" 
              Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Regular" /> 
          <On Platform="iOS" 
              Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />  
        </OnPlatform> 

        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                    x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
          <On Platform="Android" 
              Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Regular" /> 
          <On Platform="iOS" 
              Value="FontAwesome5Free-Regular" />
        </OnPlatform>
```

I want to change the fontfamily and Text value in some label on tap. I try the following code but is not working.

```
        TapGestureRecognizer starEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        starEvent.Tapped += (sender, e) => {
            Star1.FontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeSolid"].ToString();
            Star1.Text = "\uf005";
        };

        Star1.GestureRecognizers.Add(starEvent);
```

The Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeSolid"].ToString() returns me

> "Xamarin.Forms.OnPlatform`1[System.String]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `OnPlatform`. I'm not sure why it won't work like this, I guess it's related to how it's casted internally.

Try this, it should work:

```
Star1.FontFamily = (Xamarin.Forms.OnPlatform<string>)Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeSolid"];
```