# Cannot cast OnPlatform App Resource to string

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have followed a tutorial on embedding fonts in Xamarin.Forms, and in XAML I am able to use them as follows:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}" />
```

provided that in my `App.xaml` I have

```
<Application.Resources>
    ...
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
        <On Platform="Android" 
            Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Regular" /> 
        <On Platform="iOS" 
            Value="FontAwesome5Free-Regular" /> 
        <On Platform="UWP" 
            Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" /> 
    </OnPlatform>
    ...
```

Now I want to experiment it in C#, so I am casting the resource value to a string:

```
var s = (string) Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeRegular"]; // <---- KA-BOOM!
```

This raises the invalid cast exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558246/how-can-i-programmatically-access-a-resource-string-from-app-xaml#26558344) I should be able to cast it. Even the `ToString()` method gives me unhappy results:

```
        var t = Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeRegular"].ToString();
        // Xamarin.Forms.OnPlatform`1[System.String]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It returns Onplatform object and not string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212343/change-fontawesome-text-and-fontfamily-with-c-sharp-xamarin-forms

Comment: @BoredToDeath good lord I roamed on it since yesterday without finding it... Thanks!